Kerberos ticket not accepted by Exim4
I have a problem, that I cannot get solved for days. When I use name and password, I can send a mail. I see in debug output of saslauthd: response: OK
But when I use the GSSAPI method (that works for Dovecot - Kerberos is also working well) the ticket is not accepted by Exim:
gssapi_server authenticator (gssapi): Cyrus SASL username fetch problem: generic failure

This message appears, when Exim gets a Kerberos ticket or wrong login name or password as well. It is a generic message. The difference is, that in case of Kerberos ticket does not appear anything in debug output of saslauthd.
No idea, what can be wrong. The error logs are too poor. I am not able to find any guide, how to configure Exim 4 using GSSAPI. If there is something, it is mostly obsolete. (Previous working configuration I have had, is from 2016.)

PS: I am using the MIT Kerberos

Since you already run Dovecot, have you considered configuring Exim to use Dovecot SASL instead of Cyrus SASL? That would give you a much simpler system.
